# Get the latest data with Array extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
extension Array {

    mutating func fiveHundred() {

        var arrCopy = self
        arrCopy = arrCopy.reverse()

        if arrCopy.count > 0 {
            for i in 1..<250 {

                print(arrCopy[i])
                self.append(arrCopy[i])
            }
        } else {
            print("Array is empty")
        }
    }
}
```

When using it on an array it gives the error

> > "Cannot convert value of type '()' to specified type '[Double]'"

for example:

```
var data: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, ..... all the way to 1000]

data.fiveHundred() // Gives error
```

EDIT: Saw that it have <250. Sorry! I was using this on an another data array with a lot more than 250 entries.

Assume this data array have more than 250 data.

EDIT2: Here is the actual code

```
struct Data {
    let array: [Double] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
}



printData(Data.array.fiveHundred) // The function printData(val: [Double])
```

EDIT3: My apologize. The examples and question are very confusing.

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {

    mutating func fiveHundred() -> [Element] {

        var arrCopy = self
        arrCopy = arrCopy.reverse()

        if arrCopy.count > 0 {
            for i in 1..<250 {

                print(arrCopy[i])
                self.append(arrCopy[i])
            }
        } else {
            print("Array is empty")
        }
    }
}
```

This solved my a part of my problem. The another problem is that I only need maximum of 250 data. Currently its 1000.

I want to use data.fiveHundred() to get only 250 data.

EDIT4:
I finally solved it. I appreciate all the help.

extension Array where Element: Equatable {

```
mutating func fiveHundred() -> [Element] {

    var tempArr: [Element] = []

    for i in (count-1500)..<count {

        tempArr.append(self[i])
    }
    return tempArr
}
```

}

Gives me the correct array. Sorry for the confusing. Next time I have to be more clear with my question and description about the problem

Comment: @Hamish Using a function that expects [Double] and I have a double array which I use fiveHundred() on it.

Comment: @Hamish should I modify fiveHundred to return [Double]? The thing is I have different arrays with different type such as [Int] or [String]...

Comment: You should use var. Check my answer

Comment: Also, fiveHundred is void function. What do you expect from this line? printData(Data.array.fiveHundred)

Comment: Can you provide an example of input and the expected output?

Comment: Still absolutely unclear. If original array have 300 elements, what do you expect? You still mutating original array, and you now return other array at same time. What do you need?

Comment: You need to help us to understand what you really need. Please just tell us what is the expected output for these 3 examples: __(1)__ `let list0: [Double] = []` __(2)__ `let list1: [Double] = [1, 2, 3]` __(3)__
`let list2: [Double] = Array(0...999).map(Double.init)`

Comment: This question is very unclear. You're trying to get us to deduce your problem from your broken code. Which will likely fail because your code is not what you want (because it's broken). Explain to us, in English, start to finish, exactly what data you're giving as input, and what you want to get out.

Comment: Suppose (for the sake of easier examples), the `250` was scaled down to 3, and the `500` was scaled to `6`. In this transformed version of your problem, what would you want the output to be, given the input `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`?

Comment: in your EDIT 4 remove `mutating` keyword and replace all body with this single line `return Array(self[max(count-1500,0)..<count])`. Otherwise your extension is unsafe.

Answer (score 1):

`print(arrCopy[i])` gives an error because your array is `out of index` with `250`

After `arrCopy[3]` error begins, you can dismiss the error with `% arrCopy.count`

```
extension Array {

    mutating func fiveHundred() {

        var arrCopy = self
        arrCopy = arrCopy.reverse()

        if arrCopy.count > 0 {
            for i in 1..<250 {

                ///print(arrCopy[i])
                self.append(arrCopy[i%arrCopy.count])
            }
        } else {
            print("Array is empty")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Look at the edited question detail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what do you want to achieve. But if I understood well that you need to append reversed array, not more than 250 elements, not including first element, then here is solution:

```
extension Array {
    mutating func fiveHundred() {

        var arrCopy = self
        arrCopy = arrCopy.reverse()

        if arrCopy.count > 0 {
            let endIndex = arrCopy.count > 250 ? 250 : arrCopy.count
            let subArrCopy = arrCopy[1..<endIndex]
            self.appendContentsOf(subArrCopy)
        } else {
            print("Array is empty")
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this extension will work only with `var`iables, not with `let`- constants:

```
var data: [Double] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
data.fiveHundred() //ok
print(data)
//[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]
print(data.fiveHundred())
//() - because fiveHundred() is void function, it only mutate your array returning void
print(data)
//[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0] - fiveHundred() mutated data in previous print call

let data: [Double] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
data.fiveHundred() //error
```

Comment: A few improvements: `var arrCopy = self` sets `arrCopy` to a copy of `self`, but it's immediately replaced on the next line with `arrCopy.reverse()`. That if condition would probably be more appropriate as a guard. Also, using "max" for clampining to 250 would be clearer

Answer (score 0):

Here's an improvement on [Shadow Of's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38851964/3141234):

```
extension Array {
    mutating func fiveHundred() {
        guard self.count > 0 else {
            print("Array is empty")
            return
        }

        let endIndex = min(self.count, 250)
        self += self.reverse()[1..<endIndex]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think the `max` should be a `min`. And you need to define `arrCopy`.

Comment: @appzYourLife Good morning :) Can you tell I haven't had my coffee yet? :)

Comment: Ty for code revision; feel free to edit my posts if you wish

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: No problem :D

Comment: @ShadowOf I try not to make very large changes like this without the poster's permission

Comment: Since it's same logic and same result, it's ok for me; I always trying to make my code more qualitative. Ty again for pointing =)